# Query specific sheets of a google spreadsheet

Tags: database, json, google-sheets

I am attempting to use a google spreadsheet as a temporary database. I have followed the instructions at the folowing tutorial and everything is working fine

http://www.alatechsource.org/blog/2012/05/using-the-google-spreadsheets-data-api-to-build-a-recommended-reading-list-code-words.h

The jquery that gets the data I have copied below for ref

I wondered if it would be possible (using the same or similar code), assuming there are multiple sheets within the spreadsheet to query just one at a time. So for example you could run the below code but only for say sheet 4.

I have tried adding sheet ref # from the web URL (i.e #gid=1) at the end of the numeric code so

"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?"

becomes

"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE#gid=1/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?"

but this does not work, the code only seems to loop through the first sheet

Can anyone advise on this?

Any help is much appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {  

//source file is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?    key=0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE   
$(function listBooks() {    

$.getJSON( "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?",

function (data) {   

    $('div#book-list').append('<ul class="items"></ul>');

    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,entry) { 

        var item = '<span style="display:none">' + entry.id.$t + '</span>'; 

        item += '<img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' + entry.gsx$isbn.$t + '-S.jpg"/>';

        item += '<span class="meta"><a href="http://www.worldcat.org/isbn/' + entry.gsx$isbn.$t + '">' + entry.title.$t + '</a>';   

        item += '<br/>Author: ' + entry.gsx$author.$t;  

        if (entry.gsx$notes.$t) {   

            item += '<br/>Description: ' + entry.gsx$notes.$t;  

        }   

        $('.items').append('<li>' + item + '</span></li>'); 

        });

    });

});

   });


   </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I have a solution for anyone who is interested,  although it is not as sensible as I would have hoped

Thanks to the below blogpost

http://damolab.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/od6-and-finding-other-worksheet-ids.html

It seems that the id for specific sheets is the /od6/ part of the URL and od6 is the default name given to the first, default, sheet

"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?"

In the above blog post there is an example of how to find out the IDs of specific sheets if you need. There doesn't seem to be a clean logic to it but changing it will spit out the data from specific sheets so it works.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but I have been fighting this for a while. I made my own library to take care of this and I hope this saves someone many hours of research and playing with the google api. The general format is almost verbatim from the google documentation and I removed error checking to stay concise. What I could not find in the google documentation was how to query a tab that isn't the first one. I think this is what we are looking for here.

Based on what you already have, this should answer it.

`table_name_here/gviz/tq?sheet=tab_name_here`

As an example for all those that come after you:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17mbdvl1jVpqj42E3BSX34q9XUA2PbYubYKpVeypbHLA/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1`
This could be used as the table_string in the code below.

`'SELECT *'`
This could be used as the query_string in the code below.

Within context:

`function gimmeATable(){
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('table_string');
    query.setQuery('query_string');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }`

`function handleQueryResponse(response){
    var data = response.getDataTable;
    drawTable(data);
    }`

`function drawTable(data){
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('div1'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
    }`

And don't forget to include the google api as well as package type. For this you only need a table.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`


    `google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['table']});`

Comment: I tried this and it is still showing the first(default) tab data. Can someone please confirm this code works as is?